# Get values of groupBy

Tags: android, group-by, kotlin

This must be a really silly question but in the tutorials I found, they usually print all the values of a set. What if I only wanted the values corresponding to a key? Sorry, I'm new to Kotlin and OOP in general.

So for example:

```
val words = listOf("a", "abc", "ab", "def", "abcd")
val byLength = words.groupBy { it.length }

println(byLength.keys) // [1, 3, 2, 4]
println(byLength.values) // [[a], [abc, def], [ab], [abcd]]
```

How do I access only `[abc, def]` given the key `3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`println(byLength[3])`

and to access `abc` and `def` you can do

```
val tab = byLength[3]!!
println(tab[0]) // abc
println(tab[1]) // def
```

Answer (score 1):

`groupBy` returns a map. You get a value out of a map using the `[]` operator:

```
byLength[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

`byLength[3]`

This is how you index into a map in Kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

[`groupBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html) returns a `Map`, specifically a `Map<Int, List<String>>` in this case. If you need the value associated with a given key, you can use the [`get`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/get.html) method (which can also be called as an operator):

```
val v1: List<String>? = byLength.get(3)
val v2: List<String>? = byLength[3]
```

Alternatively, there's [`getOrDefault`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/get-or-default.html) which gives you a non-nullable result:

```
val v3: List<String> = byLength.getOrDefault(3, emptyList())
```